# 2 Forms, 1 Submit Button and 2 actions for CRM purposes

Tags: php, forms, submit, crm

Hi Experts,

```
          I am looking to submit two forms with one submit button and sending data to
```

two different locations. I don't know where it is possible or not but I am sure you 
experts will have some solution for this problem. Many thanks for your help in advance pls
 find the code below.

Form 1 (login) is sending data to login.php and 
Form 2 (capture Login) is sending data to CRM file capture.php.

```
 echo "<center><form name=login method=post action=getlogin.php>" ;
 echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=5>";
 echo "<tr><td>Email</td>";
 echo "<td><input type=text name=l_email size=35></td></tr>";
 echo "<tr><td>Password </td>";
 echo "<td><input type=password name=l_password size=35></td></tr>";
 echo "<form name=Capture Login action=//localhost:8888/modules/Webforms/capture.php      method=post accept-charset=utf-8>"; 
 echo "<input type=hidden name=publicid value=ec556b63988fbf6a793a1e1cf2238ef0>     </input>"; 
 echo "<input type=hidden name=name value=Capture Login></input>"; 
 echo " </p>"; 
 echo " <p>"; 
 echo " <label>Last Name</label>"; 
 echo " <input type=text name=lastname required=true>"; 
 echo " </p>"; 
 echo " <p>"; 
 echo "<label>Company</label>"; 
 echo "<input type=text name=company required=true>"; 
 echo " </p>"; 
 echo " <p>"; 
 echo "<tr><td><input type=submit value='Login'></td>";
 echo "<td><input type=reset value='Clear Form'></td></tr>";
 echo "</table>";
 echo "</form>";
 echo "</form></center>";
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can't put two forms inside each other,

what you can do is use one form add class to it and use javascript to submit values to both of your scripts, if you need help with that don't hesitate to ask.

**Example**

**html**

```
<form id="login-form" action="/loginurl" >
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="hidden" name="publicid" value="ec556b63988fbf6a793a1e1cf2238ef0"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Capture Login">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" required="true">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
function processForm() {
    //this function should make an ajax call to /modules/Webforms/capture.php
    //then submit the form by calling this.submit();
    return false;
}

var form = document.getElementById('login-form');
if (form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("submit", processForm);
} else {
    form.addEventListener("submit", processForm);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks amdorra, I am very new to PHP. Pls help me how to use javascript to make this task happen.

Comment: I am sorry amdorra as I said I am very new to this. This script is handling one form login-form what about the other form with different URL Capture Login.  Pls advise what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: you should add the capture login fields to the login-form and submit it's data using ajax to capture login then submit all data to the login form

Comment: Sorry for bother you again but this going to only 1 URL how will this perform second action and send data to 2nd URL? Like one is login.php and second is capture.php.

Comment: <form id="login-form" action="/loginurl" >

Comment: you mean something like this ?? <form id="login-form" action="/loginurl" > <form id="login-form" action="/captureurl" >

Comment: you have to make the call to the capture login script manually using ajax in the function `processForm` before using `this.submit()` as i stated in the code comment

Comment: Sorry Amdorra but I can see only 1 action="url" what about the second action??

Comment: you don't need the second action in the html you just code it in the javascript

Answer (score 0):

Ok loads of different options to do this:

1) Have 2 forms post to 2 different URLS.
2) Have 1 form post to 2 different URLS.
3) Have 1 form post to 1 URL which then does the login and the CRM (Recommended).

Why number 3? Because the doing 1 request is better than 2, especially on slow connections. It certainly will be best practise, but that being said I guess there might be a reason you want do 2 different posts.

So assuming you have basic jquery knowledge:

```
var form_one = $("#form_one").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "url_one.php",
        type: "post",
        data: form_one,
        success: function(){

            $.ajax({
                url: "url_one.php",
                type: "post",
                data: form_one,
                success: function(){
                    alert("success");
                    $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert("failure");
                    $("#result").html('error with second form');
                }
            });
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
            $("#result").html('Error with first form');
        }
    });
```

So what I am doing is:

- When you click the submit button
- I Serialize the first form and post it
- If successful, I serialize the second form and post it.

That being said, BAD PRACTISE. Submit one form, to one URL and then let the php do both logics!

Comment: Many thanks Weo, can you pls give a small example. sorry, i am very new to this

Comment: when you say data: form_one will the HTML code of forms remain the same as in my question above??

Comment: I think your answer might work but without a small example I can't apply it to my situation

Comment: Ok fixed it there, you will post the one form (form_one) to two URLS. You need to make the one PHP script do what both are doing, I can't help you with that as then I would be doing the work for you.

Comment: ok, when you say data: form_one, what does that mean? Is it something like that <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">

Comment: Also I want one information to go to one URL and second info to second URL. I do not want to send all the info sent to  two urls.